# Losing session values

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a process that involves a few .aspx pages. Fill out some info in one, hang on to it, move to another page that has an iframe on it, upload some documents in the iframe via a web service to a server, hang on to the list of documents and the status of the upload and then, on a third page, do something else that involves saving all the data to a database.

Before moving from page 1 to page 2, I put some data in Session variables. On page 2, the data is retrieved and displayed, some more data is put into Session variables during the process of uploading the files from within the page in the iframe on page 2 then, on page 3 the data is retrieved from Session and written to the database.

On a test server this all works perfectly. On a live server, I keep getting (random) 'object not set to a reference' errors - which seem to be reporting that the session variables have disappeared.

My understanding is that, within .aspx pages ...

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["myvariable"]
Session["myvariable"]
```

are, effectively, the same thing. I am setting my session variable just using ...

```
Session["Variable1"] = "fred";
```

Any ideas why (randomly, sometimes the process works fine on the live server) I seem to be losing my Session variables?

This is a web site as opposed to a web application. Developed in VS2010 using Framework 4.0

Comment: On a test server you are typically going through the application rather quickly (why wait?). Could it be that your users take more than 20 minutes (session timeout) to submit page 2?

Comment: @Hans Kesting - No, this is happening when I am testing it. I am going through pages 1 to 3 in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There can be various reasons why you are loosing the session.

Some of them are:

1. Your sessionState timeout has expired
2. You update your web.config or other file type that causes your Application Domain to recycle like files in folder App_Data
3. Your Application Pool gets recycled
4. You update your site with a lot of files just by doing copy and paste physically, and ASP.NET will automatically recycles the session.

If you are not sure of the reason you can do event logging why application pool is getting recycled. May be you will come to know about the reason and depending upon that you can take preventive measures.

For Logging you can write following code block on Application_End

```
public void Application_End()
{
    HttpRuntime runtime = (HttpRuntime)typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime",   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if (runtime == null)
        return;

    string shutDownMessage = (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    string shutDownStack = (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    //Do Logging as per your need and implementation      
    //Logging.Write(TraceEventType.Error, shutDownMessage, shutDownStack);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The is a good posiblity you save non serializable objects in you session variables and keep your session out of proc on your production server (load balancing?). Check if you objects are seriablizable and if not make them serializable.

Comment: I have an object called Supervisor. It has the properties firstName, lastName and Email. I am creating a list of that object (never more than 3 entries in the list) and saving that list in session. Are you saying my 'Supervisor' object should be serializable?

Comment: If your object goes out of proc, it need to be Serializable.

Comment: I don't manage the live server, although I can have a look - how can I tell whether session is 'kept out of proc' on the live server?

Comment: Check the msdn documentation, you will find the configuration option in this document/link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178586.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What happens is your live server is recycling its application pools, which basically resets the memory used for applications. Normally a timeout can be set, but if the application pool recycles, this will reset your session.

The solution is to use SQL server for your session state.

Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Supplemental Link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104082/Configuring-ASP-session-state-on-SQL-server

If you are hosting with a larger public host, they have probably already prepped their SQL to handle session states, and you should be able to just make the change in your `web.config` file to use SQL session state.

Ciao

Answer (score 0):

There is one more condition where sessions can lose its value.

You can use Fiddler tool to trace out this problem.

The most condition can be found when you some element like  source not found in solution. At that moment server will try to reload that unfounded or lost object by restarting the project. Restarting the project will result in resetting all session objects.

Thanks.